# Error object doesn't support property or method 'each' in jquery 1.9

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the `_on()` function to bind the mouse events. Please refer to the code below:

```
 this._on(document,"mouseup",this.ChartMouseUp);
```

When I am using `document` element, it throws the error `Object doesn't support this property or method`. When I bind with **this.element** it works fine.

What is going wrong?

Comment: What's the context here? What is `this` and what is `_on()`? Any chance of seeing a complete example?

Comment: `each`?! but there is no `each` here...?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [_on()](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#method-_on) method exposed by the base jQuery UI widget takes the following arguments:

```
_on( [ suppressDisabledCheck ] [, element ], handlers )
```

`suppressDisabledCheck` defaults to `false` (only invoke the handler if the widget is not disabled) and `element` defaults to the element the widget augments, so it looks like you want to write:

```
this._on({ mouseup: this.ChartMouseUp });
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside a jquery widget "this" refers to the widget object, while this.element refers to the element the widget has been applied on.

The _on method is used to attach event handlers to an element not the widget object.

Comment: The OP answers his own question by saying this.element works fine. From my perspective his question is why he has to use "this.element" instead of "this"

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Please refer below code

```
this._on($(document),"mouseup",this.ChartMouseUp);
```

we need to pass document as jquery object.

Thanks,

Siva